# how to solve android permission granting issue?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am listing all near by bluetooth device. for this i need to take COARSE_LOACATION permission from user for android version 6 and above.

when first time i run application it asks for permission and after granting it, it does not discover any device but on 2nd time launch it works and give list of active devices.

How can it work for first time launch.
**PERMISSION**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

JAVA CODE

```
askForPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,LOCATION);  //FUNCTION DESCRIPTION IS BELOW
ArrayList<String>mDevice=new ArrayList<>();

adapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

if(!adapter.enable()){
     adapter.enable();
  }
adapter.startDiscovery();
IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

public final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action=intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device=intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                
                mDevice.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                Log.d("Device",add+device.getName());
               list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mDevice));
            }else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action))
            {
                adapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        }
    };

private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), permission)) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

**IT WORKS AFTER FIRST LAUNCH.HOW TO FIX THIS**

Comment: After the permission request you have to start scanning using `onRequestPermissionsResult` in your activity. Your code does not stop executing to wait for permission

Comment: Please read how to correctly ask for permission https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=en